# How to add images dynamically to grid in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to add images dynamically to grid using jquery mobile. I followed the following code [jQuery Mobile grid with images and captions](http://www.vjkhan.com/jquery-mobile-jqm-grid-with-images-and-captions/). But here images are added statically. But in my project during runtime i need to add images to grid & i don't know how many it will be, so i thought of adding them dynamically. So can anyone please suggest me how to add images dynamically to grid.

I am implementing this code using phonegap plugin in android....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

```
you should go through loop and append data to parent div..

Ex:

    <div class ='ui-grid- c' id="parentDiv">

        </div>

    And your code;;
        var Items = [];
            for(var i=0;i< your_data_length:i++){
               //Add your code here
        Items.push("<div class='ui-block-b'><img src="your image source"></div>");  



        }
         $('#perentDiv').append(Items.join(''));
         $('#perentDiv').trigger('create');


    if youcan post your data list , i can post more code ..
```

/*this will be use for 2 column grid. if maor column grid is neede just chaneg the class of div as give on http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-grids.html.

Comment: Actually the data will be uploaded from server, so i just need to set code now & when pictures are added from server they need to append to grid... can you help me with this......

Comment: sure.. you need to append data inside the loop accroding you gave example.